# Error when trying to open a new SharePoint list design form in Infopath 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, infopath

I am getting the below error when i am trying to connect to the site from Infopath 2013. 
[image: infopath error]

Comment: I would check the http traffic with fiddler to see what response is coming from the server. It may be the case that some headers were removed from IIS and InfoPath doesn't know what to do.

Comment: It is a single server farm and i have installed Infopath within that server.

Comment: Try to add this site to trusted locations in InfoPath (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-remove-or-change-a-trusted-location-7ee1cdc2-483e-4cbb-bcb3-4e7c67147fb4) and also check if this site is in trusted sites or local intranet in Internet settings.

Answer (score 1):

Have you configured Alternate Access Mappings for this site? Can you connect to site before?

Try to connect to another site and check the results. If all sites cannot be connected, please make sure you enable the feature “SharePoint Server Enterprise Site Collection features” on all relevant site collection-level and site-level.

Also do not forget to try the solution mentioned above(under your question).